# How to get the url from a response?

Tags: jquery

First of all, let's say I got this piece of code:

```
 // Put the results in a div
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    var content = $( data ).find( "#content" );
    $( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
  });
```

What does the object data return from that post request? I want to get the response url from that post request, is it possible?

This is my code:

```
<form id="myForm" name="login" action="http://Xsite.com/login" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="TID" name="TID" />
    <input type="password" id="TClave" name="TClave" />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>

<script>
    $(".myForm").submit(function(event) {

      event.preventDefault();

      var $form = $( this ),
          e = $form.find( 'input[name="TID"]' ).val(),
          p = $form.find( 'input[name="TClave"]' ).val(),
          url = $form.attr( 'action' );

      var posting = $.post( url, { TID: e,TClave: p } );

      posting.done(function( data ) {
       // how to get the url for testing here?
       alert('data'); // what does this return?
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What `url` are you talking about? You should tell us what you are returning. You are most likely returning a json object. First off, `alert(data)` would give you the object, whereas `alert('data')`.

Comment: It can return anything, depends on the server side code of `http://Xsite.com/login` the url which handles your post data.

Comment: I don't have access to the server side code, is it possible to get just the url from the response? the server side code is a servlet that performs the login validation, when the credentials are not valid, it returns an url like: http://Xsite.com/index?Error=-2, can I test if the response returns that url?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to submit form and send response from post.php file to ajax success or done function

```
//script
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<form id="myForm" name="login" action="post.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="TID" name="TID" />
  <input type="password" id="TClave" name="TClave" />
  <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#myForm").submit(function(e)
{
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        dataType:'text',
        done:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
             //if done , you can also use success here
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            //if fails  
            console.log(textStatus);  
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action

});
</script> 

//post.php
<?php
print_r($_POST); //your posted data
echo "Xsite.com/index?Error=-2"; //send url when credentials are not valid
die;
?>
```

Comment: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.` It is a cross site request, maybe that's why It doesn't work

Comment: set header("access-control-allow-origin: *"); if you have access to server file.you can use jsonp but it supports only get method.Unless see http://jvaneyck.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/cross-domain-requests-in-javascript/